# How to Create Table Layout Programatically or using layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I've had some problem with rowspan, in case of using TableLayout.
I want to create layout like below image. Help me for this layout.

[image]

Comment: Is this static or will change dynamically? I mean number of rows and columns?

Comment: Please share your xml file.

Comment: Here, Number of columns are fixed. It's always 6. But Number of rows are dynamic. It will be getting from API. For ex. 1 task point have Multiple Tasks.